# Color map an image with TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm saving grayscale images in TFRecord files. The idea then was to color map them on my GPU (only using TF of course) so they get three channels (They are going to be used on a pre-trained VGG-16 model so they have to have three channels).

Does anyone have any idea how to this properly?

I tried to do it with my homemade TF color mapping script, using for-loops, `tf.scatter_nd` and a mapping array with shape = `(256,3)`... but it took forever.

**EDIT:**

```
img_rgb = GRAY SCALE IMAGE WITH 3 CHANNELS

cmp =  [[255,255,255],
        [255,255,253],
        [255,254,250],
        [255,254,248],
        [255,254,245],

        ...

        [4,0,0],
        [0,0,0]]


cmp = tf.convert_to_tensor(cmp, tf.int32) # (256, 3)
hot = tf.zeros([224,224,3], tf.int32)



for i in range(img_rgb.shape[2]):
for j in range(img_rgb.shape[1]):
    for k in range(img_rgb.shape[0]):
        indices = tf.constant([[k,j,i]])
        updates = tf.Variable([cmp[img_rgb[k,j,i],i]])
        shape = tf.constant([256, 3])
        hot = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape)
```

This was my attempt, I know it's not optimal in any way, but It was the only solution I could come up with.

Comment: Can you please post the code you used. It is quite unclear (to me) what you're exactly trying to do, especially how would `tf.scatter_nd` fit into the story. A _for loop_ sounds something that should be optimized away...

Comment: If you're training a network, you probably want to put your image preprocessing on the CPU for faster training. You can look into using [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) to implement the color mapping in python and bringing it into tf as an op

Comment: @PeterSzoldan , I used `scatter_nd` to index items in the image so I could assign values to the image the with `cmp` color mapping. @KRish , as a fairly new TF user, what is the advantages of using an op?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're here to help. If everyone wrote optimal code, there would be no need for Stackoverflow. :)

Here's how I would do it in place of the last 7 lines (untested code):

```
conv_img = tf.gather( params = cmp,
                      indices = img_rgb[ :, :, 0 ] )
```

Basically, no need for the for loops, Tensorflow will do that for you, and much quicker. [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) will collect elements from `cmp` according to the indices provided, which here would be the 0th channel of `img_rgb`. Each collected element will have the three channels from `cmp` so when you put them all together, it will form an image.

I don't have time to test right now, gotta run, sorry. Hope it works.

Comment: This kinda worked, thank you! It's not the HOT color map look I'm looking for, but it's fast! Do you know how to get the color right?

Comment: Wait, the hot colors are right when I use `scipy.misc.imshow`, and not right when I use `plt.imshow`. I guess it works, just some modes in `plt.imshow` that are not right.

Comment: Happy to hear it worked! :) Whenever you have _for_ loops it's much slower than doing it tensors (with some rearrangement if necessary.) The image showing problem is probably because you use `int32` as datatype for `cmp` and one might use that as `int8` (correctly) and the other might try to interpret it as `float32` (incorrectly.) Try using `int8` for `cmp`'s data type, that should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks work by jimfleming, https://gist.github.com/jimfleming/c1adfdb0f526465c99409cc143dea97b

````
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm

import tensorflow as tf

def colorize(value, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None):
        """
        A utility function for TensorFlow that maps a grayscale image to a matplotlib
        colormap for use with TensorBoard image summaries.
        Arguments:
          - value: 2D Tensor of shape [height, width] or 3D Tensor of shape
            [height, width, 1].
          - vmin: the minimum value of the range used for normalization.
            (Default: value minimum)
          - vmax: the maximum value of the range used for normalization.
            (Default: value maximum)
          - cmap: a valid cmap named for use with matplotlib's `get_cmap`.
            (Default: 'gray')
        Example usage:
        ```
        output = tf.random_uniform(shape=[256, 256, 1])
        output_color = colorize(output, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, cmap='plasma')
        tf.summary.image('output', output_color)
        ```

        Returns a 3D tensor of shape [height, width, 3].
        """

        # normalize
        vmin = tf.reduce_min(value) if vmin is None else vmin
        vmax = tf.reduce_max(value) if vmax is None else vmax
        value = (value - vmin) / (vmax - vmin) # vmin..vmax

        # squeeze last dim if it exists
        value = tf.squeeze(value)

        # quantize
        indices = tf.to_int32(tf.round(value * 255))

        # gather
        cm = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap(cmap if cmap is not None else 'gray')
        colors = tf.constant(cm.colors, dtype=tf.float32)
        value = tf.gather(colors, indices)

        return value
````

You could also try `tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb`, although there seems to be only one choice of color map, `gray`.

Comment: A gotcha: code only works for `ListedColormap`, not `LinearSegmentedColormap`. replace `cm.colors` line with `cm.colors if isinstance(cm, matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap) else cm(range(256))` to handle both